# We have an international standard: C++0x is unanimously approved. Where can I find the latest draft/copy?

Tags: c++, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents)

Great. Like many of you I want to be well prepared when the new C++ standard hits the street (industry) and start studying it before it's officially published.

Please point me where it can be downloaded.

Comment: I suspect the official standard will come with a fee much like C++98. You can always look at the various drafts that are available though.

Comment: Asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents

Answer (score 6):

You could either purchase the official final PDF [here](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=50372), or download the most recent draft free of charge [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf).

Comment: If you wait a bit, national resellers (such as BSI) will probably undercut ISO.

Answer (score 2):

The latest draft that is still publicly downloadable at no cost is the Feb 2011 draft:

- http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf

Comment: As far as I know the drafts usually *stay* free of charge, which is usually why most people on the internet reference the drafts instead of the final version (you can't easily link to a for-pay resource).